# Краевая задача. Разностный метод

Tags: математика

Мне нужно решить следующую краевую задачу с начальными условиями:

`y''-sin(y)= exp(x), y(1) = 2, y(0) = 1`

В разностном методе я должен выбрать коэффициенты для расчета.

В моем случае:

**A = 1 , B = 0** , **f=exp(x)**. Но чему равен коэффициент **С**? К примеру, если бы у меня было **-y**, тогда понятно, что коэффициент был бы равен **-1**, но чему будет равен коэффициент в таком случае: **-sin(y)**?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас в принципе нет коэффициента `C`. Ваше уравнение нелинейное, а уравнение для разной схемы, которое вы привели, - линейное. Одно к другому не сводится.

Comment: @PakUula  т.е. этим разностным методом это ур-е не решить, верно?

Comment: Да методом конечных разностей настолько нелинейное уравнение не решить. у вас `у` достаточно велик, чтобы синус у нельзя было линеаризовать. Метод конечных разностей для нелинейных уравнений так просто не работает. Нужна итерационная схема, чтобы последовательно искать приближения к `y(x)`.

Comment: Можно это нелинейность обойти "методом стрельбы", подбирая начальное значение `y'(0)` таким, чтоб потом было `y(1)==2`.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в принципе нет коэффициента `C`. Ваше уравнение нелинейное, а уравнение для разностной схемы, которое вы привели, - линейное. Одно к другому не сводится.

Методом конечных разностей настолько нелинейное уравнение не решить. У вас `у` достаточно велик, чтобы синус у нельзя было линеаризовать. Метод конечных разностей для нелинейных уравнений так просто не работает. Нужна итерационная схема, чтобы последовательно искать приближения к `y(x)`.

Если вам интересно, решение вашей краевой задачи выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для [численного решения](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16VUe4DvJwrwgKwkIZWL9MBrm9f1Kg3k9?usp=sharing) использовался пакет `scipy`. В нем для решения краевой задачи используется приближение решения кусочно-полиномиальными функциями. Общий метод решения изложен в статье https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/502800.502801